# What Eclipse products are there by default?

Tags: eclipse

I have a number of Eclipse versions installed. I noticed they have different icons in my task bar. The reason for this are different lines in the `eclipse.ini` files:

```
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

versus

```
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

My question is now: What is the relevance of this? What does it affect? Anything besides the icon? What other products are there hidden in a normal Eclipse download?

I understand this comes from different downloads, but in the end it does not matter much which version you start with when you can add all the plugins.

**EDIT**: Assume I download the Java EE version, but like the icon of the standard Java version better. What ill effects can be expceted if I change the `-product` line in `eclipse.ini`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now used an Eclipse download that was labelled as JEE (and used the `jee` product) for quite a while as a Java product and was not able to notice any difference except for the icon. Therefore, I have come to believe this is indeed the only effect.

Answer (score 0):

Packages depend on the version of Eclipse you downloaded, e.g. the Modeling. Java EE, C++, etc..

If you go to the [downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and click on the names of the various versions it lists the packages included by default.  Sometimes there are difficult dependencies or incompatibilities you can run into when downloading each plug-in separately, so the downloads serve as a collection of plug-ins guaranteed to run 'out-of-the-box'.

I pretty sure all versions come with Mylyn, JDT, and CVS.  Although these are all developed separately, they are considered so fundamental or useful to Eclipse they are included.